# Querying huge amount of data in sqlserver?

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008, jpa, jpql

Am working in a project where retrieving data from database takes time since the **number of records** are more than **2000** . 
Am using **JPQL** to query the database and display it in **JQGRID** .

**Can any one suggest or guide me how to query huge amount of data from database which takes less time .**

I am happy to provide any kind of extra information needed

Also please guide me if there is already a solution ....

Thank you ....

Comment: 2000 records is not huge. 2 billion records is huge.

Comment: yeah i understood . but as of now in testing environment its 2000 records. But in future it may go upto your count .. if it takes time to query 2000 records , then think how much time it will take to to retrieve 2billion records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is profile your query to see where your time is being spent.  45 seems like an insane amount of time to read 2,000 records.  On a simple desktop I can read over 10,000 simple objects in less than 1 second.  Are your objects very complex?

You might want to enable logging as a start, it could be your time is being spent fetching relationships, (the n+1 problem).

If you are using EclipseLink you can enable the PerformanceMonitor, it can give you a profile dump of where your time is being spent.  Using a Java profiler such as JProfiler would also be good.

See also,
http://java-persistence-performance.blogspot.com/2011/06/how-to-improve-jpa-performance-by-1825.html

Answer (score 1):

Before we can successfully tell you how to solve your problem you need to narrow down where the problem is occurring. Take your query that is generating your resultset and run it directly against the database using SSMS to see how long the pure query takes to execute. If it executes very quickly, then your problem is in the UI. If it's in the actual database server performance itself, then you need to look at query tuning and optimization and potentially your indexes.

There are many articles available on the latter subject such as the one below:

http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2004/query-tuning/

Answer (score 0):

You should use pagination. See [jqGrid documentation](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) for some examples (PHP with MySql, but it shouldn't be too difficult to adapt it to Sql Server and JPQL).

Comment: am using pagination . everything works fine . but i want to reduce the amount of time to get the data .. now its taking 45 appro.sec  to fetch 2300+ records

Comment: But are you displaying 2300 records per page? You should show just a few records (say 20), and fetch just those records from the database